# Replace double backslash with single backslash in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I have created a regular expression with re-builder in Emacs. I use C-c C-w to copy it to the kill-ring.

The kill-ring shows:

```
"\\(defun\\)"
```

First, I modified the copy function to get rid of the "".

```
\\(defun\\)
```

My other problem is, the regex in the kill-ring contains double backslashes, rendering it unusable for functions like *query-replace-regexp*, which I want to yank it back into from the kill-ring.

These functions expect single backslashes, like

```
\(defun\)
```

So I thought I could replace the '\\' with the '\' before copying it to the kill-ring by doing this:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "\\" "\\(defun\\)" nil t)
```

When executing the function the minibuffer shows "\\(defun\\)" instead of "\(defun\)" as a result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(defun my-reb-copy ()
  "Copy current RE into the kill ring without quotes and single
backslashes for later insertion."
  (interactive)
  (reb-update-regexp)
  (let* ((re (with-output-to-string
               (print (reb-target-binding reb-regexp))))
         (str (substring re 2 (- (length re) 2))))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert str)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "\\\\" nil t)
        (replace-match "\\" nil t))
      (kill-new (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))
    (message "Regexp copied to kill-ring")))

(define-key reb-mode-map "\C-c\C-t" 'my-reb-copy)
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing your string through `'insert` or `'princ` does the substitution for you.

```
(princ "\\(defun\\)")
->
\(defun\)
```

I don't see the obvious way to do this directly, here's a really convoluted way that seems to work with the test strings for me:

```
(defun my-insert-kill ()
  "convoluted way to replace \\ in strings"
  (interactive)
  (princ (with-temp-buffer
           (insert "(progn (princ ")
           (insert (current-kill 0))
           (insert ") (insert \"\n\") nil)")
           (eval-print-last-sexp)
           (backward-sexp) (backward-char)
           (let ((p (point)))
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (forward-sexp) (forward-char)
             (buffer-substring (point) p)))
         (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: Yes, evaluating in a buffer like *scratch* I could do the same thing with (while (search-forward "\\\\" nil t) (replace-match "\\" nil t)), while of course your solution is a lot easier, but I need to wrap it in a command somehow.

Answer (score 1):

re-builder+.el has some extensions to re-builder that provides functions for using re-builder with `query-replace-regexp` and `replace-regexp.`

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/re-builder+.el

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(defun my-yank-unstring ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (car (read-from-string (current-kill 0)))))
```

(Thanks to Trey for the `(current-kill 0)` bit.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, you could set the variable `reb-re-syntax` to `string` instead of the default `read`. This will change the behavior of `re-builder` to [use single backslashes instead of double](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder).

To do this using customize:

```
M-x customize-variable RET rev-re-syntax RET
```

Or add to your .emacs file:

```
(set reb-re-syntax 'string)
```

Then, to jump directly into replacement, you could use [this defun](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReBuilder):

```
(defun reb-query-replace (to-string)
  "Replace current RE from point with `query-replace-regexp'."
  (interactive
   (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
          (list (query-replace-read-to (reb-target-binding reb-regexp)
                                       "Query replace"  t))))
  (with-current-buffer reb-target-buffer
    (query-replace-regexp (reb-target-binding reb-regexp) to-string)))
```